# How to emit all input value as object from child component back to parent component?

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework

I would like to get all the inputs value as an object and pass back to parent component, and perform some action on the value. Is there a way to do so? Appreciate all the comments

- Parent Component

```html
<template>
  <table-filter v-model:tableFilter="state.filter"/>
</template>
<script setup>
const filter = ref({});
</script>
```

- Child Component

```html
<template>
  <div class="col">
    <q-input
      outlined
      dense
      v-model="tableFilter.name"
      @update:model-value="emit('update:tableFilter', tableFilter)"
      placeholder="Name"
      class="q-mr-md-sm"
    >
      <template v-slot:prepend>
        <q-icon name="search" />
      </template>
    </q-input>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <q-select
      outlined
      dense
      v-model="tableFilter.country"
      @update:model-value="emit('update:tableFilter', tableFilter)"
      :options="countryList"
      label="Country"
      map-options
      emit-value
      hide-bottom-space
      clearable
    />
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <q-select
      outlined
      dense
      v-model="tableFilter.location"
      @update:model-value="emit('update:tableFilter', tableFilter)"
      label="Location"
      :options="locationList"
      emit-value
      map-options
      clearable
      hide-bottom-space
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { PropType, ref } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
  countryList: {
    type: Object,
    default() {
      return {};
    },
  },
  locationList: {
    type: Array as PropType<Array<string>>,
  },
});

const emit = defineEmits(['update:tableFilter', 'reset']);

const tableFilter = ref({});
</script>
```

Expecting Result of object from parent component

{
name: 'abc',
country: 'abc',
location: 'abc'
}

Comment: So, your thing is not working? What do you see in your Vue devtools?

Comment: Actually is working just that I'm getting one input value at a time, what I want is all the input value as an object